# Start program in user folder without knowing user name

Tags: java, runtime, directory, home-directory

I have no idea if I can just run this code and it will work but here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try
        {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("c:\\Users\\Toby\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\minecraft.exe");
        }

        catch(Exception a)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is linked to a button, and it launches the minecraft launcher. If I want to give it to my friends, what do I have to do so that it doesn't look for the user 'Toby', but instead looks for their home folder? Sorry if its confusing!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! Its worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `user.home` property. There's a list of properties available here: http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm

So, your code would be changed to:

```
Process p = rt.exec(System.getProperty("user.home") + \\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\minecraft.exe");
```

Comment: Well, it's not an endorsement of the website. I found another resource and updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep consistency with other version of Windows, I would suggest using the `System.getenv("APPDATA")` instead of adding to `System.getProperty("user.home")` because *Roaming* folder is not present in older version of Windows

So your code would change to something like this:

```
Process p = rt.exec(System.getenv("APPDATA") + ".minecraft\\minecraft.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.getProperty("user.home")`

```
String mhome = System.getProperty("user.home"))+"";

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try
            {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rt.exec(mhome+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\minecraft.exe");
            }

            catch(Exception a)
            {

            }
        }
```